# how to setup cron using php in dreamhost?

Tags: php, cron

I'm wondering how to make this cron job work in a dreamhost server:

```
    $cron = '15 * * * * /usr/local/php71/bin/php '. ' /home/username/run.php >> /home/username/cron.out';

    try{

    $output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
    $job = '';
    $cronfile = '/home/username/tmp/crontab.txt';

    file_put_contents($cronfile, " ");   
    $job = $output . ' ' . $cron;
    file_put_contents($cronfile, $job . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);    
    echo exec('crontab ' . $cronfile);
    echo 'Successful cron job task';
    }catch(Exception $ex){
        error_log("Errors while setting up cron $ex");
    }
```

This is what's in the run.php:

```
<?php
error_log("Called from cron job");
?>
```

But I don't see any logs coming from run.php. What should I do to properly configure and have a successful cron job?